# Suitability of Mule ESB

Tags: mule

We have developed an application that is split into several components. Each component is actually designed as a Linux process. They communicate point-to-point with each other over a custom developed communication mechanism. We have now decided to use Websphere MQ for communication due to issues with the comm mechanism.

Some of these components are in Java and some in C++. These components are all custom developed and we are not using third-party systems. One key feature is that at certain 'times' like 6:30, 7:00 ,... we need to tell component1 to do something and once it is done, component2 should be told to do something else.

Is Mule suitable for orchestration of this kind, and that too among processes which are completely in our control?

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Yes, orchestration is right smack in the sweet spot of Mule.

But why going to Websphere MQ? When readiog the first two lines of your question I thought it had ZeroMQ painted all over...